# meaning of [!_] and ls -lt *xyz* 2 > dir

Tags: unix, ksh

I have a code which includes the line below:

```
old_fil=`ls -lt [!_]*xyz* 2> /dev/null | grep -v ^total | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}'`
```

Can you explain the meaning of `[!_]` and `2` in `ls -lt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[..]` matches any character that is listed inside.

But if the first character is `^` or `!`, it matches any characters not in the specified characters.; `[!_]` match characters that is not `_`.

Following command lists files that whose name does not starts with `_` (it should match a chracter) and contains `xyz`:

```
ls [!_]*xyz*
```

---

`2` in `2>` means file descriptor. (0 = standard input, 1 = standard output, 2 = standard error).

By appending `2> /dev/null`, error messages generated by the command will be discarded.

Comment: He needs explanation of `2>`, not `t`.

Comment: I am getting "ls: [!_]*xyz*: No such file or directory" even though i have _xyz.txt file and a xyz.txt file

Comment: @rinu, I updated the answer. Sorry, I forget `[!...]` means negation.

Comment: @rinu, `xyz.txt` does not match because `x` matches `[!_]` (and now there's no `xyz` remained.)

Comment: Thanks falsetru. But I am not convinced as why xyz.txt is not captured in this. The command means any file with xyz but should not start with _ . Then why xyz.txt is not captured??

Comment: @rinu, `x` matches `[!_]` parts, now `yz.txt` part remains. Remaining part does not match `*xyz*` because there's no `xyz`.

Comment: @falsetru , isnt xyz taken as single entity and checked against     [!_] first and then againt *xyz* in the ls part?

Comment: @rinu, `[!_]` not only match, but it also consumes(?) matched part from the string.

Comment: @rinu, Think of the pattern as character by character (except `*`).